# plot world map with areas coloured according to categorization based on latitude in R

Tags: r, dictionary, plot, rworldmap

I would like to colour geographical areas according to the values of a specific column ("Value), where the geographical areas are not Countries nor Continent, but areas defined by latitude ("North Temperate Zone", "Torrid Zone", "South Temperate Zone").

An example dataset:

```
df_ex <- data.frame(Area = c("North Temperate Zone", "Torrid Zone", "South Temperate Zone"), Value = c(2.8, 1.0, 4.3))
```

I tried with `joinCountryData2Map` and `mapCountryData` but the only categorization available seems to be the Country.

Any ideas?

Comment: AFAIK `joinCountryData2Map` doesn't recognize your area codes because it wants countries. You probably need to `merge` a dataframe with countries e.g. in ISO3 format to these areas or latitudes respectively to your `df_ex`.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this by getting the centroid of each country and assigning the latitude to a zone using `cut`. There are some problems with this of course; many countries span different zones, and some countries include overseas dependencies in completely different zones.

These issues aside, the basic approach would be something like this:

```r
library(rnaturalearth)
library(sf)
library(tidyverse)

world_map <- ne_countries(returnclass = 'sf')

world_map %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(lat = tryCatch(st_centroid(geometry) %>%
                               st_coordinates() %>% getElement(2), 
                             error = \(e) {
                               st_coordinates(geometry) %>%
                                 as.data.frame() %>%
                                 getElement(2) %>%
                                 mean()}),
         lat = cut(lat, breaks = c(-91, -66.5, -23.5, 23.5, 66.5, 91), 
                   labels = c('South Frigid', 'South Temperate', 
                              'Torrid', 'North Temperate', 'North Frigid'))) %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_sf(aes(fill = lat)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = c(-66.5, -23.5, 0, 23.5, 66.5), linewidth = 0.1,
             color = 'gray20') +
  scale_fill_manual(NULL, values = c('#D8D8FF', '#D8FFD8', '#90B860',
                                     '#A8FFD8', '#A8D8FF')) +
  theme_void() +
  theme(legend.position = 'bottom')
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe you missed it, but OP asks about the `rworldmap` package.

Comment: Ah, you mean the tag @jay.sf? Yes, I did miss that. I'm not sure how important that specific detail is to the OP as long as the output is correct, but maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: @AllanCameron thanks for the answer, but this solution gives a fix colour for each area chosen by the user. Instead, I'd like to obtain a darker/lighter colour according to the value of a specific column.

Comment: @jeff the first part of this answer (before the ggplot line) creates a data frame where each country is assigned to one of the zones. All you need to do is left join your data onto this data frame and fill by the value column

Comment: @AllanCameron I've done the left join, the problem is that i get the following error "Error in wk_handle.wk_wkb(wkb, s2_geography_writer(oriented = oriented,  : 
  Loop 0 is not valid: Edge 0 crosses edge 78" when I collapse data by Country in order to have one row for each area (instead of one row for each Country). Otherwise when I fill by the value column I get different colours for each country (instead I want the same colour for countries within the same area)